# Count number of people using their ID number in certain age range

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a tabel with two columns. First column is a pesonal ID number, second column is a name. I need to sum how many kids are in range between ages 5 and ages 16 (older than 5 and younger than 16) using their ID number (which contains date of birth).

Example:

```
ID                  Name
_________________________
0906013123588   |   Name1
1508007128536   |   Name2
1603008120746   |   Name3
2705983123601   |   Name4
0101018125432   |   Name5
```

Result should be:   3

First 7 digits of an ID number represent date of birth next 6 digits are a control number (which doesnt interest me at this point).

Comment: First of all you should extend your table with a column for persons birthday.

Comment: What is the format of the date in the ID?

Comment: @cdaiga day, month, year

Comment: @cdaiga DD/MM/YYY

Comment: @DCO 7 digits so it's 09/06/013 => 09/06/2013

Comment: @DCO 0906013 = 09.06.2013. = DDMMYYY

Comment: I dont know if mysql can handle format yyy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to clean up your database design.
You could create a new table and transform your data to that new table programmatically.
Your new table should contain a seperated date column for date_of_birth.

I think MySql is not able to handle format yyy.
It can just handle yy or yyyy. 
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp

if the format would be correct you could do something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM person_table 
WHERE
DATEDIFF(
  CURRENT_DATE,
  STR_TO_DATE(
    SUBSTRING(
      CONVERT (ID,char)
      ,0,6
    ),'%d%m%y'
  )/365
BETWEEN 5 AND 16
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that and let you know how it went.

Answer (score 2):

I would not use `datediff()` for this purpose.  I would simply compare the birthdate to the appropriate birthdate range:

```
SELECT pt.* 
FROM person_table pt
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(LEFT(ID, 6), '%d%m%y') > curdate() - interval 16 year AND
      STR_TO_DATE(LEFT(ID, 6), '%d%m%y') <= curdate() - interval 5 year;
```

You need to be careful with the two-digit years.  After all, the id doesn't handle people over 100 years old very well.